React-native maps doesn't show up
I'm trying to display a map for my react-native project.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import { useAuth } from "../navigation/AppNavigator";
import { GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY } from "../../assets/apiKeys";
import MapView, { Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import { mapStyles as styles } from "../styles/mapStyles";

const MapScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { user } = useAuth();
  const [address, setAddress] = useState(null);
  const [region, setRegion] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      (async () => {
        try {
          const { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
          if (status !== "granted") {
            console.error("Location permission not granted");
            return;
          }
          const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
          const { latitude, longitude } = location.coords;
          setRegion({
            latitude: latitude,
            longitude: longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.01,
            longitudeDelta: 0.01,
          });
          // Call the geocoding API to convert coordinates into an address
          const response = await fetch(
            `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${latitude},${longitude}&key=${GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}`
          );
          const data = await response.json();
          setAddress(data.results[0].formatted_address);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error retrieving location:", error);
        }
      })();
    }
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {user ? (
        <>
          <Text>Welcome, {user.name}!</Text>
          {address && <Text>Your current address: {address}</Text>}
          {region && (
            <MapView
              provider="google"
              style={styles.map}
              initialRegion={region}
              showsUserLocation={true}
            >
              <Marker
                coordinate={region}
                title="Your Location"
                description={address}
              />
            </MapView>
          )}
          {region && <Text>Your current address: {address}</Text>}
          {address && <Text>Your current address: {address}</Text>}
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Text>You must be logged in to view this page</Text>
          <Button
            title="Go to Login"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Account")}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default MapScreen;

My map definitely has styles as here is my Mapstyles file:
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export const mapStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  content: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  map: {
    width: "300",
    height: "300",
  },
});

However I don't see anything on my mobile Android device.
I'm using expo go.
I tried placing it outside the view container, generating new API key and even set this API key to no restrictions.
I have maps sdk for android enabled.
What is weird I don't see any requests for it, but for geocoding API there are multiple requests noted by my panel (because this part works):
 const response = await fetch(
            `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${latitude},${longitude}&key=${GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}`
          );


Could you please provide us with a sample application so we can better check it?
